# No bitcoin.conf file on my (Mac) node?

Tags: bitcoin-core, mac, bitcoin.conf

I installed a full node on my old Mac (running on Catalina 10.15.7) and though running well it looks like it will go over my ISP's monthly data limits. I was thinking I'd try changing the maxconnections in the bitcoin.conf file, but I'm not seeing that file under Application Support, even when I reveal hidden files. Do I need to create it or should I be looking elsewhere?

Full Node Noob

Answer (score 0):

Yes, no config file is created by default. If you want one, you need to create it yourself.

Without config file, all settings stay at their built-in default values.